# Returning value from catch/finally in java?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

I have below code. if query is executed without exception then true should return, if any exception is thrown then false should be returned. and finally statement and connection should be closed.
my question is where should i write return statement? in catch or finally? in below code i am returning true in try if query is executed, and false in catch if any exception is thrown. my question is if any exception is thrown, does returning false and closing connection and statement happens?

```
try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery("select * from dual");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
                   return false;
        } finally{
                try {

                        statement.close();

                        connection.close();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

        }
```

Comment: I think where it is is just right. Your resource logic is not good though. Consider using try-with resoruces if you're using java 7.

Comment: Why don't you tried it yourself? Put a `System.out.println` statement on every possible execution path and debug yourself? You will learn and remember it better that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work as you've written it. To execute the return with the `finally` block properly, you need to keep state, i.e.

```
boolean result = false;

try
{
 // all good
 result = true;
} 
catch(...)
{
 // crap
 result = false;
}
finally
{
 // close
}
return result;
```

This assumes that you want what's in the `finally` block to be executed and the correct result to be returned.

Comment: Not sure what you mean to say, but `finally` will always be executed, even if you `return` from the `try` or `catch` block.

Answer (score 8):

In neither, write it outside the try-catch block, below it. **NEVER USE RETURN IN THE FINALLY BLOCK** as that return statement would be executed always, trampling over your regular return statement in the try-block!

Answer (score 5):

> where should i write return statement?

Put it right at the very end, after the final `}`:

```
    try {
        ...
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ...
    }
    return false; // <===== HERE
```

This way the function would return `true` if and only if the code within the `try` blocks executes without throwing an exception. In all other cases, the function would return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet try using JDK 7 and use the new try with resources.

Comment: Yes, try-with-resources was made for this situation. Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
boolean returnVal = false
try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery("select * from dual");
            returnVal = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    returnVal = false;
    } finally{
            try {

                    statement.close();

                    connection.close();


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
         returnVal = false;

            }
    return returnVal;

    }
```